# spring-data-jpa count distinct with Specifications

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

In spring-date-jpa,  when my specification contains query.distinct(true) i see that the count(Specification) method, the count query is incorrect. 
The generated SQL looks like this :

select distinctcount(*) ...

Instead of

select count(distinct(*)) ...

In that post:[spring-source-forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124497-is-there-any-way-to-do-a-count%28distinct%28%2a%29%29-using-Specifications) 
The workaround was to mofify the source code of spring-data-jpa.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another workaround:

```
Subquery<Class1> sq = query.subquery(Class1.class);
Root<Class1> spouseEmp = sq.from(Class1.class);
sq.select(spouseEmp);
sq.where(builder.equal(spouseEmp.get("class2"),class2.get("class2")));
predicate.getExpressions().add(builder.exists(sq));
```

Answer (score 0):

CriteriaBuilder has a countDistinct that should get you want you want. I know this question is years old but I've been hunting for this answer for sometime.  I was running into a similar issue where query.distinct(true) was not working as expected when used with count. In my example I was using a Specification. Posting this answer to raise awareness for `countDistinct`

```
public TypedQuery<Long> getCountQuery(Specification<T> spec) {

  CriteriaBuilder builder = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
  Root<?> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, query);
  query.select(builder.countDistinct(root));

  return this.em.createQuery(query);
```

}